# Problem to pass variable parent to child in SSIS 2016 on Datafactory Azure

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, ssis-2016

The pipeline works on DataFactory Azure (SSIS 2016) with no call child package.
When my parent package called child package, the variable child doesn't replace by a variable parent. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right , I think what you are suggesting is that you are using ADF , and you are trying to call a child pipeline from a parent pipeline .

What you need to do is on the parent pipeline , please pass the values  as an parameter to the child pipeline and you should be able to access that from the child pipeline .

[image]